# jQuery validation and css position

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, position

I have the following page: http://valogiannis.com/freelancer/neurosport/register.html

I use a validation jquery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

When the user types a text inside the text fields and if the text is valid then a check image appears.

The plugin add a `label` inside the `td` with class `registerInput` and below the `input`.

So I used `position:relative` to position the image in the left side of the input. But this create a gap between the input fields. How can I position the auto created label before the input field?

Any solution with css or jquery is appreciated, or any trick of the validation plugin I use to position the label in a specific place (in fact I have created a `td` for this with class `registerIcon`.

Comment: I appears to be the validation label, not the image, creating the gap. Though it empties it and appears to be missing, it is still being displayed as a block element (thus inducing a new line). -- Try to change the way the label is handled and have it apply `display:none;` when the error is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using margin:-XX; works :)